# Flows on a manifold as a group action.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

A flow on a manifold $M$ is a one-parameter group of diffeomorphism $\psi_t: M \to M$. In particular, this induces a smooth group action on $M$, 
$$ \mathbb{R} \times M \to M $$ 
$$ (t,m) \mapsto \psi_t(m)$$
So that we have a group homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to Diff(M)$.

My question is the following: Given any diffeomorphism $g \in Diff(M)$, does there exist a flow (and thus a vector field) on $M$ such that $g$ is in the image of $\phi$?

Comment: I added the "differential-topology" tag to your post.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no, and the reason may be concisely stated:  for any flow

$\phi: \Bbb R \times M \to M \tag 1$

each

$\phi_t: M \to M, \; \forall x \in M \; \phi_t(x) = \phi(t, x) \tag 2$

is homotopic to the identity map, *via* a homotopy

$H(s, t, x) = \phi_{st}(x), \; s \in [0, 1]; \tag 3$

it is easily seen that

$H(0, t, x) = \phi_0(x) = x, \; H(1, t, x) = \phi_t(x). \tag 4$

For many $M$ there are, however, diffeomorphisms $\psi:M \to M$ which are not homomtopic to the identity; an example is provided by [the antipodal map $\psi(x) = -x$ on $S^{2n}$](http://planetmath.org/antipodalmaponsnishomotopictotheidentityifandonlyifnisodd) for any positive integer $n$.

Comment: More interestingly, there are even diffeomorphisms isotopic to the identity that are not in the image of any flow: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1643274/28513

Answer (score 1):

No, the group of diffeomorphism of a manifold is not always connected, for example for the torus, the connected components are in bijection with $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_class_group_of_a_surface

Comment: Ok. So we definitely would need a manifold to be connected for this to hold. Does it necessarily hold for, let us say, compact, connected manifolds?

Comment: The two dimensional torus is connected.